# Issues with AWS Lambda event handling - mangled JSON input

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've got this vexing issue that I can't figure out if it's my API Gateway integration or if the client I am using is mangling JSON.

```
2021-05-24T22:37:50.654+00:00   START RequestId: f84d5c8a-28cb-440e-99c3-92936ec3b96b Version: $LATEST
    2021-05-24T22:37:50.658+00:00   Event:
    2021-05-24T22:37:50.658+00:00   {'version': '2.0', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'rawPath': '/Prod/core', 'rawQueryString': '', 'headers':
 {'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'content-length': '998', 'content-type': 
'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'host': 'xyz123.execute-api.us-
east-2.amazonaws.com', 'user-agent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)', 'x-amzn-trace-
id': 'Root=1-60ac2abe-14b492b063c8224d6251a0f9', 'x-forwarded-for': 
'24.160.100.69', 'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'}, 
'requestContext': {'accountId': '4792', 'apiId': 'xyz123', 'domainName': 

'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'domainPrefix': 'xyz123', 
'http': {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/Prod/core', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 
'sourceIp': '24.10.10.69', 'userAgent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)'}, 
'requestId': 'f2udzgoWCYcEMtg=', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'stage': 
'Prod', 'time': '24/May/2021:22:37:50 +0000', 'timeEpoch': 1621895870604},
 'body': '{"message":"this is a test 
message","cookie":"duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw"}', 'isBase64Encoded': 
False}

    2021-05-24T22:37:50.658+00:00   Context:
    2021-05-24T22:37:50.658+00:00   <__main__.LambdaContext object at 0x7fb29be47a00>
    2021-05-24T22:37:50.659+00:00
[ERROR] ValueError: malformed node or string: {'version': '2.0', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'rawPath': '/Prod/core', 'rawQueryString': '', 'headers': {'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'content-length': '998', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'host': 'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'user-agent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-60ac2abe-14b492b063c8224d6251a0f9', 'x-forwarded-for': '24.10.10.69', 'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'}, 'requestContext': {'accountId': '4792', 'apiId': 'xyz123', 'domainName': 'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'domainPrefix': 'xyz123', 'http': {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/Prod/core', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'sourceIp': '24.10.10.69', 'userAgent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)'}, 'requestId': 'f2udzgoWCYcEMtg=', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'stage': 'Prod', 'time': '24/May/2021:22:37:50 +0000', 'timeEpoch': 1621895870604}, 'body': '{"message":"this is a test message","cookie":"duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw"}', 'isBase64Encoded': False}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    body = ast.literal_eval(event)['body']
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 99, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 98, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 75, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 66, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 63, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
```

So it doesn't look like valid JSON or at least json.loads throws an exception so I tried using ast in my function handler:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    body = ast.literal_eval(event)['body']
```

Any ideas would be super helpful, I'm trying to nail down why the JSON isn't being passed properly here and if this is some type of API Gateway proxy integration issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your `event`?

Comment: The event is printed in the log above, I tried to fix the Markdown formatting so that you can see it. It looks like half of the payload is single quote escaped instead of double quote escaped which throws the exception with json.loads. The body tag it looks like it's having the issue with.

Comment: The event and your code are fine. The error must originate from other parts of your code which are not shown.

Comment: it's difficult to tell from your original post, but is there a newline in the `message:` text?

Answer (score 0):

The `event` you received is okay. I tested this the following way:

- copy/paste of the event as seen in the log into a variable
- removal of the `\n` just for human readability while testing
- `eval()` of the resulting string to turn this into an actual `dict`, which should fail if invalid
- result check

This test shows this is a proper `dict`:

```
>>> copy_pasted_from_question='''{'version': '2.0', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'rawPath': '/Prod/core', 
... 'rawQueryString': '', 'headers':
... {'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'content-length': '998', 'content-type':
... 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'host': 'xyz123.execute-api.us-
... east-2.amazonaws.com', 'user-agent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)', 'x-amzn-trace-
... id': 'Root=1-60ac2abe-14b492b063c8224d6251a0f9', 'x-forwarded-for':
... '24.160.100.69', 'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'},
... 'requestContext': {'accountId': '4792', 'apiId': 'xyz123', 'domainName':
... 
... 'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'domainPrefix': 'xyz123',
... 'http': {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/Prod/core', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1',
... 'sourceIp': '24.10.10.69', 'userAgent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)'},
... 'requestId': 'f2udzgoWCYcEMtg=', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'stage':
... 'Prod', 'time': '24/May/2021:22:37:50 +0000', 'timeEpoch': 1621895870604},
...  'body': '{"message":"this is a test
... message","cookie":"duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw"}', 'isBase64Encoded':
... False}'''

>>> one_liner = copy_pasted_from_question.replace('\n', '')

>>> one_liner
'{\'version\': \'2.0\', \'routeKey\': \'POST /core\', \'rawPath\': 
\'/Prod/core\', \'rawQueryString\': \'\', \'headers\': {\'accept-encoding\': 
\'gzip\', \'content-length\': \'998\', \'content-type\': \'application/json; 
charset=UTF-8\', \'host\': \'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\', 
\'user-agent\': \'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)\', \'x-amzn-trace-id\': \'Root=1-60ac2abe- 
14b492b063c8224d6251a0f9\', \'x-forwarded-for\': \'24.160.100.69\', \'x- 
forwarded-port\': \'443\', \'x-forwarded-proto\': \'https\'}, 
\'requestContext\': {\'accountId\': \'4792\', \'apiId\': \'xyz123\', 
\'domainName\': \'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\', 
\'domainPrefix\': \'xyz123\', \'http\': {\'method\': \'POST\', \'path\': 
\'/Prod/core\', \'protocol\': \'HTTP/1.1\', \'sourceIp\': \'24.10.10.69\', 
\'userAgent\': \'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)\'}, \'requestId\': \'f2udzgoWCYcEMtg=\', 
\'routeKey\': \'POST /core\', \'stage\': \'Prod\', \'time\': 
\'24/May/2021:22:37:50 +0000\', \'timeEpoch\': 1621895870604}, \'body\': 
\'{"message":"this is a test 
message","cookie":"duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw"}\', \'isBase64Encoded\': 
False}'

>>> will_fail_if_not_a_valid_dict=eval(one_liner)

>>> will_fail_if_not_a_valid_dict
{'version': '2.0', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'rawPath': '/Prod/core', 
'rawQueryString': '', 'headers': {'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'content-length': 
'998', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'host': 
'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'user-agent': 'Dart/2.10 
(dart:io)', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-60ac2abe-14b492b063c8224d6251a0f9', 'x- 
forwarded-for': '24.160.100.69', 'x-forwarded-port': '443', 'x-forwarded-proto': 
'https'}, 'requestContext': {'accountId': '4792', 'apiId': 'xyz123', 
'domainName': 'xyz123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'domainPrefix': 
'xyz123', 'http': {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/Prod/core', 'protocol': 
'HTTP/1.1', 'sourceIp': '24.10.10.69', 'userAgent': 'Dart/2.10 (dart:io)'}, 
'requestId': 'f2udzgoWCYcEMtg=', 'routeKey': 'POST /core', 'stage': 'Prod', 
'time': '24/May/2021:22:37:50 +0000', 'timeEpoch': 1621895870604}, 'body': 
'{"message":"this is a test 
message","cookie":"duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw"}', 'isBase64Encoded': False}

>>> type(will_fail_if_not_a_valid_dict)
<class 'dict'>
```

Now that we know for a fact the `event` is valid, I tried to retrieve its body and to load it assuming it consists of valid JSON. This worked properly:

```
>>> import json
>>> body = json.loads(will_fail_if_not_a_valid_dict['body'])

>>> body
{'message': 'this is a test message', 'cookie': duhIULXn7fz6WtqPdfwl5MM7lm1yrw'}
```

So there might have been a mistake in the first version of your code. I think this because you said:

> So it doesn't look like valid JSON or at least json.loads throws an exception

Maybe you erroneously did something like:

```
json.loads(event)['body'] # Raises TypeError: "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"
```

instead of:

```
json.loads(event['body']) # Only the body is expected to be in JSON, not the whole event which is a dict
```

Anyway, your first idea of using `json.loads()` was perfectly correct, and so is the data.

*As a sidenote*: I'm in the process of developping a library called `awsmate` to make the use of common AWS services easier. Maybe it could be useful to you. It is there: https://github.com/shlublu/awsmate

Using it, a lambda handler that retrieves the body of a an API Gateway proxy Lambda event and returns it to the caller would look like this:

```
from awsmate.apigateway import LambdaProxyEvent, build_http_response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event_object = LambdaProxyEvent(event)
    body = event_object.query_payload()

    return build_http_response(200, body, event=event_object)
```